# WP7 Default dates

Tags: windows-phone-7, locale, date, timestamp, defaults

I have released an app which,. within its functionality displays date and time strings.

I am aware of the differing formats across cultures - however in some cases I had hardcoded values- for example I had gone with  a custom format that was the 12 hr clock and showed  AM/PM

I am now changing to use the standard date time format strings where possible, and so, for my times,I am now using the shortTimePattern.

What has surprised me is that for the US this shows as say 3:15PM but in the UK its 16:15 i.e the default there is the 24 hr clock.
Similarly in the US the long date includes the day of the week, where as in the UK it does not.

I am thinking that these defaults  must be right and are what is expected within that country but is this really the case?  I had no idea that the UK default would be a 24 hr clock.  And, for those users in the UK who have the app, will they be annoyed when the next update shows the time in this format?

Interested in any opinions around this.

- thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UK Users will not care between 24hr and am/pm (we don't talk to each other saying "It's fourteen hundred o'clock :P).

Dates are also fine unless you're using format of 12/02/12 as in the UK that's considered 12th Feb whereas in the states it's December 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the place to solicit "opinions" on whether the behaviour provided by the framework is correct.

Assume that the framework is correct, unless you know otherwise.

If you want to know what your users will think you should ask them. (I assume that your users are not typical users of StackOverflow.) If you don't already have beta users in your target markets to ask then make the change to use the "standard" behaviour. If there is a problem your users will tell you.